# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY only during evaluation phase

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I am using tensor flows `tf.train_and_evaluate` along with google's cloud ai jobs system to train a `tf.estimator.Estimator` model.

Recently, when I go to train my model, I get a `CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY` error while training, but I have noticed that this only occurs during the `evaluation` phase. I.e. I can run the training for an arbitrary number of steps, but as soon as the training phase is up I see the error.

I have copied and pasted the exact errors (there are several in a row) below:

```
failed to alloc 8589934592 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
out of memory
could not allocate pinned host memory of size: 8589934592    
failed to alloc 7730940928 bytes on host: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY:    
out of memory could not allocate pinned host memory of size:
7730940928 failed to alloc 6957846528 bytes on host:
CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory could not allocate pinned host
memory of size: 6957846528 failed to alloc 6262061568 bytes on host:
CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE: invalid argument could not allocate pinned
host memory of size: 6262061568 failed to alloc 5635855360 bytes on
host: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE: invalid argument could not allocate
pinned host memory of size: 5635855360
```

Comment: What is the evaluation batch size you are setting for your job? How does it compare ti the training batch size?

Comment: Is this a distributed training job? I have seen this error where distributed jobs are using a unique GPU and since by default TF uses all GPU memory available in a single machine when a new process tries to access it dumps this error.